# R: Is there a way to match values between two numeric columns up to "n" decimal places?

Tags: r

If I had the data frame:

```
x <- c(554.233, 540.331, 113.541, 722.320)
y <- c(540.330, 178.132, 722.321, 342.872)
df <- data.frame(x,y)
print(df)

        x       y
1 554.233 540.330
2 540.331 178.132
3 113.541 722.321
4 722.320 342.872
```

What would be the best way to index for matching values between the two columns up to two decimal points (i.e. 540.331 in x column and 540.330 in y column would be matched)? Once I've extracted the matching values I'd also like to align the matched values in x and y next to each other. Something along the lines of:

```
        x       y
1 554.233      NA
2 540.331 540.330
3 113.541      NA
4 722.320 722.321
```

I'm quite new to R and coding in general, so apologies in advance for any formatting mistakes or information left out. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could apply `` `-` `` with `outer`, which gives you a matrix with the differences.

```
(o <- outer(df$x, df$y, `-`))
#          [,1]     [,2]    [,3]     [,4]
# [1,]  -13.903 -376.101 168.088 -211.361
# [2,]   -0.001 -362.199 181.990 -197.459
# [3,]  426.789   64.591 608.780  229.331
# [4,] -181.990 -544.188   0.001 -379.448
```

Then you may define a `tol`erance and check in an `apply` `which` `abs`olute differences are less or equal to `tol` and if not, `NA`. Finally select `df$y` by using brackets.

```
tol <- .001
df$y.match <- apply(o, 1, function(x) {
  w <- which(abs(x) <= tol)
  if (length(w) < 1) NA else df$y[w]
})
df
#         x       y y.match
# 1 554.233 540.330      NA
# 2 540.331 178.132 540.330
# 3 113.541 722.321      NA
# 4 722.320 342.872 722.321
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use `match` on the `round`ed value

```
df$y <- with(df, y[match(round(x), round(y))])
df
#        x       y
#1 554.233      NA
#2 540.331 540.330
#3 113.541      NA
#4 722.320 722.321
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Any way to do it without rounding? Ideally I'd want a value like 540.331 and 540.338 to be matched together to account for some variation between experiments.

Comment: @yj94lim would `540.331` and `540.340` be equal

Comment: I'm just trying to be as conservative as I can at this stage. For my current purposes I'd consider 540.331 and 540.338 close enough to warrant being matched together.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `round`. + `format` to keep values only till 2 decimal places and then compare the values with `match`.

```
df$y <- df$y[match(format(round(df$x, 2), nsmall = 2), 
                   format(round(df$y, 2), nsmall = 2))]
df

#        x       y
#1 554.233      NA
#2 540.331 540.330
#3 113.541      NA
#4 722.320 722.321
```